# Android context error

Tags: android, android-context

I have the following class:

```
package com.somedomain.enigma;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;

public class APICall {
    private String DEBUG_TAG = "enigma";

    public void register(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String URL = "http://somedomain.com:8888/register";

        String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
        String unregistered = intent.getStringExtra("unregistered"); 

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

        // Send a POST to the server to register the device
        if (registrationId != null) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registrationId", registrationId));
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if(responseCode == 200) {
                    SharedPreferences settings = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("registrationId", registrationId);
                    editor.commit();
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Device registered successfully");
                } else {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Device registration failed");
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (unregistered != null) {
            // get old registration ID from shared preferences
            // notify 3rd-party server about the unregistered ID
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Unregister request");
        } 

        if (error != null) {
            if ("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".equals(error)) {
               // optionally retry using exponential back-off
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Service not available");
            } else {
                // Unrecoverable error, log it
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Received error: " + error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I am receiving the error `"The method getPreferences(int) is undefined for the type Context"` on this line:

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I am passing in context from the previous method using `Context context = getApplicationContext();` any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencesName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Straight from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), there is no `getPreferences` method, but there is a `getSharedPreferences()` method.

Note that if you are using a default SharedPreferences file, [you can do](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29)

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

**Edit:** [`getSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences%28int%29) is only part of the `Activity` class. This method is actually a convenience method.

> This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int)
>   method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences
>   name.

So if you are absolutely sure that `context` is an instance of Activity you can change the method declaration:

```
public void register(Activity activity, Intent intent) {
```

or cast

```
SharedPreferences settings = ((Activity)context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

However, if `context` is **not** an instance of Activity, you will have to rely on the other approaches for accessing Preferences.

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't read enough, I saw this code sample but I guess it's just for an Activity. 'SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);'

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Only an Activity method.

Comment: @user2004988 that's only part of the Activity [class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)) so yes, you're right :)

Comment: @user2004988 You're welcome :-) Feel free to accept this answer (click the hollowed out checkmark).